# Janela popup em javascript e css

Tags: javascript, html, css

Estou fazendo uns cards que quando eu clico em entrar ele mostra no meio da tela um popup com as infos de cada card , fiz uma função em javascript , o card 1 deu certo , mas o card 2 ele abre as infos do card 1 , sera que eu teria que criar uma função de open e close  para cada card ?

HTML

````
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Card Hover Effects</title>
    
</head>

<body>
    

    <div class="container">
    
        <div class="card">
            <div class="content">
                <h2>R001</h2>
                <p>Consulta DBE</p>
                <a href="javascript:open();">Entrar</a>
                <div id="popup" class="popup">
                    <p> Roda na VM01 ás 7hrs e 15 hrs <br>   
                        Se der Terminated porque não achou tela de login no site da receita, rodar de novo.
                         Em algumas VMs esse erro acontece por não achar o botão para prosseguir
                          (preenche o CPF e depois clica nesse botão) para a tela de login.
                           A Fernanda coloca manualmente o zoom do navegador em 200%, aí ele acha o botão.
                            Se rodar na madruga apenas em uma VM, não precisa rodar em outra. 
                            Se tiver itens na fila, pode rodar logo de manhã, senão,
                             deixa pro próximo agendamento. Não tem problema rodar mais q 2x e nem 1x, 
                             mas o correto são 2 vezes ao dia, Madrugada e a tarde.
                              Tem 2 agendamentos na madrugada, porque em alguns dias, 
                              tem 200 itens para processar, mas em geral é na faixa de 20 itens. 
                              Só faz consulta, nada de lançamento.</p>
                    <a href="javascript: close();">Fechar</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="card">
            <div class="content">
                <h2>R002</h2>
                <p>Payment Inquiry</p>
                <a href="javascript:open();">Entrar</a>
                <div id="popup" class="popup">
                    <p> Roda na VM01 ás 7hrs e 15 hrs <br>   
                        Se der Terminated porque não achou tela de login no site da receita, rodar de novo.
                         Em algumas VMs esse erro acontece por não achar o botão para prosseguir
                          (preenche o CPF e depois clica nesse botão) para a tela de login.
                           A Fernanda coloca manualmente o zoom do navegador em 200%, aí ele acha o botão.
                            Se rodar na madruga apenas em uma VM, não precisa rodar em outra. 
                            .</p>
                    <a href="javascript: close();">Fechar</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="card">
            <div class="content">
                <h2>R003</h2>
                <p>Proposta Item</p>
                <a href="#">Entrar</a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="card">
            <div class="content">
                <h2>R004</h2>
                <p>Admissão</p>
                <a href="lista.php">Entrar</a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="card">
            <div class="content">
                <h2>R005</h2>
                <p>Payment GRM</p>
                <a href="">Entrar</a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="card">
            <div class="content">
                <h2>R006</h2>
                <p>Rescisão</p>
                <a href="">Entrar</a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="card">
            <div class="content">
                <h2>R007</h2>
                <p>Conciliações Bancarias</p>
                <a href="">Entrar</a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="card">
            <div class="content">
                <h2>R008</h2>
                <p>Pagamentos RH</p>
                <a href="">Entrar</a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="card">
            <div class="content">
                <h2>R009</h2>
                <p>Fretes</p>
                <a href="">Entrar</a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="card">
            <div class="content">
                <h2>R010</h2>
                <p>Prposta Item fluxo</p>
                <a href="">Entrar</a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="card">
            <div class="content">
                <h2>R011</h2>
                <p>IES</p>
                <a href="">Entrar</a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="card">
            <div class="content">
                <h2>R012</h2>
                <p>KIT Rescisão</p>
                <a href="">Entrar</a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="card">
            <div class="content">
                <h2>R013</h2>
                <p>Evidências</p>
                <a href="">Entrar</a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="card">
            <div class="content">
                <h2>R014</h2>
                <p>Inventário de Tanques</p>
                <a href="">Entrar</a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="card">
            <div class="content">
                <h2>R015</h2>
                <p>Comex</p>
                <a href="">Entrar</a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="card">
            <div class="content">
                <h2>R016</h2>
                <p>Background Check</p>
                <a href="">Entrar</a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="card">
            <div class="content">
                <h2>R017</h2>
                <p>Ànalises RC PATI</p>
                <a href="">Entrar</a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="card">
            <div class="content">
                <h2>R018</h2>
                <p>Envio de Layout</p>
                <a href="">Entrar</a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="card">
            <div class="content">
                <h2>R019</h2>
                <p>Processamento NF Serviço P72</p>
                <a href="">Entrar</a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="card">
            <div class="content">
                <h2>R020</h2>
                <p>Alteração Cadastro Frota</p>
                <a href="">Entrar</a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="card">
            <div class="content">
                <h2>R021</h2>
                <p>Processamento NF Serviço Moove</p>
                <a href="">Entrar</a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="card">
            <div class="content">
                <h2>R022</h2>
                <p>Simulação de NFs de Material</p>
                <a href="">Entrar</a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="card">
            <div class="content">
                <h2>R023</h2>
                <p>Envio de Relatórios CIA</p>
                <a href="">Entrar</a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="card">
            <div class="content">
                <h2>R024</h2>
                <p>Relatórios Comercial</p>
                <a href="">Entrar</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    
    <div class="card">
            <div class="content">
                <h2>R025</h2>
                <p>Rodada MRP</p>
                <a href="">Entrar</a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="card">
            <div class="content">
                <h2>R026</h2>
                <p>Chamados CRD</p>
                <a href="">Entrar</a>
            </div>
            </div>
            
    </div>
    
</body>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function open(){
        document.getElementById('popup').style.display ='block';
        
        }
    function close(){
        document.getElementById('popup').style.display='none';
    }
    
    
    </script>

</html> ```

-

** CSS **

``` <style>
    @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poppins:300,400,500,600,700,800&display=swap');
*
{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
}


#logo{
    margin-top:-550px;
    margin-left:-160px;
    border-radius:10px;
    -webkit-box-reflect:below 1px linear-gradient(transparent,#0005);
}
.popup{
    position: absolute;
    justify-content: center;
    top: 100px;
    margin: auto;
    width: 800px;
    height: 600px;
    padding: 10px;
    border: solid 1px #4c4d4f;
    background: #f5821a;
    display: none;
    transition: 0.5s;
    
    }
body
{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    min-height: 100vh;
    background: linear-gradient(0deg,#fff 50%, #2196F3);
    background-repeat:repeat;
}
.container
{
    max-width: 1000px;
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    transition: 0.5s;
}
.container:hover .card
{
    filter: blur(0px);
    transform: scale(.7);
}
.container .card
{
    position: relative;
    width: 250px;
    height: 300px;
    background: #fff;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    transition: 0.5s;
    border-radius: 10px;
    transform: scaleY(1);
    transform: scaleX(0.9);
    transform: scale(.8);
    


}
.container .card:hover
{
    filter: blur(0px);
    transform: scale(1);
}
.container .card:before
{
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: #2196F3;
    z-index: 1;
    transition: 0.5s;
    border-color: #000;
    border-radius: 10px;
    
}
.container .card:hover:before
{
    background: #000;
    transform: scaleY(1.15);
    box-shadow: 0 5px 15px rgba(0,0,0,.2);
}
.container .card:after
{
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 50%;
    height: 100%;
    transition: 0.5s;
    background: rgba(255,255,255,.1);
    z-index: 1;
}
.container .card:hover:after
{
    transform: scaleY(1.15);
}
.container .card:hover
{
    z-index: 1;
}
.container .card .content
{
    text-align: center;
    z-index: 2;
    padding: 0 20px;
    transition: 0.5s;
}
.container .card:hover .content
{
    color: #fff;
}
.container .card .content h2
{
    font-size: 2em;
}
.container .card .content p
{
    font-size: 0.9em;
}
.container .card .content a
{
    display: inline-block;
    margin-top: 15px;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    background: #262626;
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.container .card:hover .content a
{
    background: #2196F3;
}
</style>```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Opa nicholas, para resolver o problema ai é bem simples. Como você está deixando de forma estática na função que o popup que vai ser aberto é o de `id="popup"`, ele sempre vai interagir com esse elemento.

Uma forma de resolver isso é passar o id do popup que você quer como parâmetro no seu click, daí a função fica dinâmica de acordo com o elemento que você quiser :)

```
    // pega o id como parâmetro para referenciar o elemento na DOM
    function open(id){
       document.getElementById(id).style.display ='block';
    }

    function close(id){
       document.getElementById(id).style.display='none';
    }
```

Então no seu html, ficaria assim, em cada elemento:

```
href="javascript:open('popup');"
href="javascript:open('popup2');"
```

Um exemplo:

```js
function funcaoLegal(idElemento) {
        document.getElementById(idElemento).style.display = 'block'
    }
```

```css
.quadrado {
        display: none;
        height: 100px;
        width: 100px;
        background-color: #b00;
        margin: 10px;
    }

    #quadrado2 {
        background-color: #bb0;
    }

    #quadrado3 {
        background-color: #3b7;
    }

    #quadrado4 {
        background-color: #307;
    }
```

```html
<body>
    <a onclick="funcaoLegal('quadrado1')">Quadrado 1</a>
    <a onclick="funcaoLegal('quadrado2')">Quadrado 2</a>
    <a onclick="funcaoLegal('quadrado3')">Quadrado 3</a>
    <a onclick="funcaoLegal('quadrado4')">Quadrado 4</a>

    <div class="quadrado" id="quadrado1"></div>
    <div class="quadrado" id="quadrado2"></div>
    <div class="quadrado" id="quadrado3"></div>
    <div class="quadrado" id="quadrado4"></div>
</body>
```

Espero ter ajudado, abraço :)

Comment: opa obgdo , entao eu teria que fazer uma função para cada card? eu pensei isso e fiz , mas achei que dava pra fazer somente uma função e abrir os popups de cada card , passando o id no onclick por exemplo , quase igual o seu que vc mandou

Comment: Opa, não esquece de marcar a pergunta como respondida. E tem como fazer isso também, no caso você se refere a escrever em todos os elementos a função né? Nesse caso você teria que criar uma função pegando qualquer clique no elemento `<a>` que você deseja por exemplo. Daí, não precisaria ficar declarando no html em todos os botões.